# How to make system startup to not wait on particular systemd service start

Tags: startup, systemd

I have few virtual machines running under libvirt, and they are stared on the host system startup. This is controlled by libvirtd.service systemd configuration.

This delays the availability of the host system tty until all the virtual guests are started.

How should I configure systemd to not wait on successful start of libvirtd, and leave it to start in the background?

Comment: what distribution is this?

Comment: opensuse, but it shouldn't matter